# SetEnv with php.ini

Tags: php, iis-6, setenv

I initially set up a website on a LAMP server, but my employer needs it moved to a WISP (windows/iis/sql server/php .. I don't think this is a real term?) server, which I have done.  I'm using IIS v 6, and I read that there is no `SetEnv` equivalent where you can set `_SERVER` variables.  I rely on these variables for some configuration like the DB user/password and a site key for hashing.  I'd strongly prefer to keep these out of the php code for security reasons.

The only solution I can think of is setting such variables with php.ini.  I believe you can set a default DB connection, but I'd prefer not to do this anyway.  Does php.ini have a `SetEnv` equivalent?

If not, is this possible to do with IIS anyway?

For example I want to be able to use a custom `_SERVER[db_user]` or `_SERVER[site_key]`.  In my current .htaccess I have

```
SetEnv db_user tandu
SetEnv site_key blocked_for_your_protection
```

Comment: The SetEnv syntax is Apache only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set server variables in your `php.ini` file. Check the output of a `phpinfo()` command where this file is on your server.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) about the [php.ini settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

To edit the `_SERVER` settings, you have to set those directly in your server:

**Apache:** works with htaccess and `SetEnv`
**IIS:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php in your *.php file or in the config:

```
<serverVariables>
    <set name="db_user" value="abc" />
    <set name="site_key" value="abc" />
</serverVariables>
```

See http://forums.iis.net/t/1171675.aspx

You can check your result on your phpinfo page. The variables must occur there!

Comment: Great.  *how* do you set server variables in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: I mean customer server variables like `_SERVER[db_user]` or `_SERVER[site_key]`

Comment: Please add those variables to your question above!

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need.  I'd prefer to have it in the server configuration than to use putenv() in the code even if the code is not under the web root.

Comment: If you have the final solution, please post it here.

Comment: I will.  Can't do it now, but tonight.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set a real enviroment variable with `Start > Control Panel > System > Environment` and read that. Then the settings are visible to all the software running on the machine, though.

Comment: This appears to be the master value that takes priority. Followed by the IIS server (application settings environment variable [local]) which can be inherited per site or overridden by each site's own local environment variable. I believe this last one is stored in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP script (usually index.php) I use -

```
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

This checks the possible hierarchy of places that the value might be stored and defaults to 'production' in the ternary condition as above.

On local ( which runs Apache) this gets it value from the     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 in ../Apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\wwwroot\foo"
    <Directory "C:\wwwroot\foo">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    ErrorLog "logs/foo.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/foo.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development" could also have been placed in .htaccess and I assume that .htaccess gets priority.

When I deploy to the production server the constant APPLICATION_ENV gets its value from IIS root server name Application Settings of the same name (all sites on this server inherit from the root but you can give them their own local environment variable).

The environment variable that *can* be created Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings-System Variables seems to get priority. The IIS root. Then Individual sites.